# How does Neo4j indexing (using lucene) work under the hood?

Tags: lucene, neo4j

A few questions relating lucene indexes in Neo4j and how they're used during queries and traversal. Basically, the way relationship are stored on disk (a linked list), it seems to me that any graph traversal would require to sequential  visit all relationships for a node - not sure how an index could be used in this case. More specifically:

1) When node properties are indexed, how would that be used for a query such as "all my female friends of friends" (gender is indexed). The only way I see an index being used it by first finding all friends of friends, and then submitting a  query to lucene to get all the females. Is it faster than just doing to comparison in memory though?

2) When relationships properties are indexed. Since the relationships are stored in a linked list, it's impossible to get a subset of relationships for a node without sequentially walking the list. I suppose we could always index relationships using node_ids but that seems silly - we end up storing adjacency lists in both lucene and Neo4J

Answer (score 3):

Indexes are not used for traversals.

They are only used to find your starting points in the graph.

Depending on the relationship-types and directions you only traverse a subset of relationships from a node.

For your query 1, you don't need an index on gender, as it will return about 50% of the people in your graph. But you would use an index for the initial user lookup (me)

create index on :User(name);

MATCH (m:User {name:"Me"})-[:FRIEND]->(other:User) 
WHERE other.gender = "female"
RETURN other;

2) yes, you are right.

You can do that, but it is only necessary if you have *a lot* of relationships (millions) and want to access a tiny slice of those.

So if that's your use case a relationship-index might help.
Relationships are actually indexed with both node-id's and a relationship-property

Comment: Thanks Michael! It's just that if we have 10 types relationships, iterating through all of them just to find one type doesn't sound efficient. But I guess the performance is still constant (with growing number of nodes/relationships) as opposed to a RDBMS B-tree which is log(n)

Comment: In my case, I want to find all 3rd degree friends that match certain criteria (gender, age, distance, etc). Depending on the network size, the traversal will return anywhere from 1000 (20 friends/ user) to 100,000+ (50+ friends/user) matches. Would it make more sense to the retrieve the friends list from neo4J and perform the filtering elsewhere(Lucene or even an RDBMS with proper indexes)?